Cypress tests in Electron with Server Sent Events
I cannot receive server sent events when running cypress e2e test. Tested in Electron and Chromium browsers. Connection seems to be established successfully but no events are received. Does anyone have a working example of how it should be done?  I am using Angular and sse.js library for EventSource with custom authentication header.
Checked network tab - response status 200, but no events in EventStream
Checked console - no errors
Works correctly when run locally with ng serve
Cypress config
import {defineConfig} from 'cypress';

export default defineConfig({
  projectId: 'my-project-id',
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
    testIsolation: true,
    video: true,
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
  },

  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'angular',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
    specPattern: '**/*.cy.ts',
  },
  env: {
    username: 'frontend-cypress-test',
    password: '',
  },
});


Password is provided as env variable:
CYPRESS_password=my-password npx cypress open
Angular service which handles connection to SSE:
private connectSse = () => {
    console.log('create new SSE');
    this.keycloakService.getToken().then((token) => {
      this.eventSource = this.getEventSource(token);

      this.eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        console.log('SSE message:', event.data);
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          if (event.data !== BEAT) {
            this.messagesSubject.next(JSON.parse(event.data));
          }
        });
      };

      // Close the SSE connection on page unload
      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
        this.eventSource.close();
      });
    });
  };

private getEventSource(token: string) {
    const eventSource = new SSE(this.baseUrl + '/sse', {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}});

    eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('EventSource failed:', error);
      this.eventSource.close();
      setTimeout(this.connectSse, 5000);
    };

    return eventSource;
  }




How have you set up and tested? If you give better details you will get a better answer.

People tend to ignore questions with a lot of details, what's why I asked initially only for an example code. But I have added details as you've suggested

Thanks, BTW is it e2e or component test, or does not matter?

This is e2e test

Can Cypress work with SSE at all? There is unresolved issue:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/24284

I notice setTimeout(this.connectSse, 5000) which indicates the connection isn't made until at least 5 seconds after the app loads. What does the test look like? Does it account for the startup delay?

setTimeout does not affect the test. Connection is established immediately and  setTimeout is called in order to reconnect in case of an error only.

If you take a look at this issue on the Cypress GitHub site:
Server sent events don't work and seem to be buffered by the Cypress proxy. #1440
Brian Mann seems to have resolved the issue back in Cypress version 3.0.2 with this pull-request:
add support for handling event streams / server sent events / SSE #2054
hally9k provided a simple repo for the problem here:
https://github.com/hally9k/cypress-sse.
I ran his repo, tweaking the test to avoid race conditions between the test and the event messages.
cy.visit('./index.html')

// receiving events
cy.get("#incrementer").as('inc', {type:'static'})  // fastest way to check 
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "ready")
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "1")
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "2")
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "3")
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "4")
cy.get('@inc').should("have.text", "5")

// closing connection
cy.get("#connection-state").should("have.text", "Open")
cy.get("#close-connection-button").click()
cy.get("#connection-state").should("have.text", "Closed")


This is the event stream on the network tab:


Notes

I tried to substitute the NPM package sse.js, but it didn't work (I don't have time for a full debug)

the web page is plain javascript, not Angular so your issue may be there (but unlikley if it works w/o Cypress)

I experimented with cy.intercept() in the test, as it looks like it should work - but the messages did not appear even though the intercept caught the initial connection request, and I set it to req.continue().
cy.intercept('http://127.0.0.1:9876/sse', (req) => req.continue())

This may be the issue for your app if you have also used an intercept.



The Angular Service
From this Leveraging Server-Sent Events (SSE) with Angular, you don't need a library import to use SSE in the client, as it's widely supported by the EventSource` API in the browser.
This is their example service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventService {

  sse: EventSource

  getEventData(){
    return new Observable(obs=>{
      this.sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/curr-count');

      this.sse.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }

      this.sse.onmessage = (message) => {
            obs.next(JSON.parse(message.data).count);
      }
    })
  }
}


thank you for the detailed answer. It seems that the problem is that Cypress does not support EventSource from sse.js library. I had to switch to event-source-polyfill despite serious warning regarding using this library. But seems that only sse.js and event-source-polyfill work in Angular with custom headers.

You are using the server component of sse.js. The client component works as above.

After switching from sse.js to event-source-polyfill Cypress receives server-sent-events correctly. Maybe Cypress does not support that particular EventSource which is used by sse.js.
I hesitated to try event-source-polyfill however due to serious warning about it (I believe authors wouldn't put "Do not use this sh**ty library" without a reason in the description).


This is the clue - event-source-polyfill is for use when the browser does not natively support EventSource, but it's no longer needed since there is now wide support.

This article Leveraging Server-Sent Events (SSE) with Angular and Node.js is a good example. The Angular service only needs this.sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/curr-count');.. Note that EventSource does not need an import of anything.

The SSE library is for creating the server, which you start separately from the front-end (unless I'm missing some new trick from Angular).

Native EventSource does not support authorization headers and, therefore, cannot be used when endpoint is protected by authentication. Which is the most of the real cases in web applications. That's why libraries with extended EventSource are used.

If you want header you should be using extended-eventsource
